# My app supports armv6 and armv7 in the app store. I want to remove armv6. How to solve a problem

Tags: iphone, app-store

My app supports armv6 and armv7 in the app store. It is ready for sale. I want to remove armv6. 
I decided to do an update (my app with only armv7). But i received an error in the app loader : update must supports armv6 and armv7.
How to solve a problem.

Comment: Why do you want to remove armv6 support?  The original iphone and iphone 3G don't support armv7 (nor do the 1st/2nd gen ipod touches), so doing this would prevent your app running on those devices.

Comment: my app works very slowly on 3g, (it needed 256 RAM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you can't restrict device capabilities after submission. From the iTunes Connect Manage Applications FAQ:

"To change device requirement information after your first binary has been submitted, you must submit an application update in iTunes Connect to provide a new binary with the new information in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key. **You are permitted to expand your device requirements only. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your device requirements is not permitted.** " [emphasis added]

I've been looking for a way around this, or for Apple to specifically allow removal of armv6 support with the approach of iOS5 release. Crossing fingers. :-/

Comment: How about upgrading target to **4.3**, will it be legal now to remove **armv6**? **Note that armv6 does not run 4.3!**

Answer (score 1):

In xcode, go to your project's build settings.  Update your deployment target to ios 4.3.

(im using ios5/xcode4)

Comment: That's a great solution if you only want to support 4.3 and above, but at the time we were required to support back to 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in your info.plist? This might be your problem, [check the Apple Q&A here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1707/)

Comment: yes, i did this. But i cann't upload new version. app loader : update must supports armv6 and armv7.